# add Ant Design with ejected create-react-app project in Webpack config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

The tutorial here: https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app
only tells how to integrate Antd with CRA app.

I ejected my cra app and need to add Antd into my project. I guess I wouldn't need to install the "react-app-rewired" as I have already ejected my project, so I should be able to directly go somewhere to configure it.

As I want to use the "modularized antd", so i installed "babel-plugin-import"

Then I need to add this:

```
config = injectBabelPlugin(['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'es', style: 'css' }], config);
```

in my **webpack.config.dev.js** (I guess, because I can't find any document about it)

Inside this file, I have located the section:

```
module.exports -> plugins:[...]
```

I just miss the last step about how and where to put this code.

### Update

Once I tried it works, but it seems that the antd styles affect the existing style. Here is the original look of the webpage:

[image: The original look]

and here is the after look(after Antd is added)

[image: with Antd]

You can see that the h2 a p elements are all affected. This is unwanted and shouldn't happen as the modularized import from Antd should only import styles for button.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        // Process JS with Babel.
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve( 'babel-loader' ),
            options: {
                plugins: [
                    [ 'import', [ { libraryName: 'antd', style: 'css' } ] ],  // Ant Design
                ],

                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
            },
        },
```

This is without less. For less and themeing I located a version of the docs that has instructions for your setup: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/be238c788775990d4f15c9f83c16ca4db7226271/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app.en-US.md

Comment: great~! it works!  With only 1 problem, the antd css seems affecting my existing css style. I will upload the screenshot to show what I mean. I just wonder why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, but antd is not intended to be used only for a standalone button. It is more of an all or nothing solution. The good thing being that the antd "all" is a *much* more feature complete "all" than any other widget library. So antd does a whole lot of CSS normalization before it even begins to render a widget.

Comment: okay. I was reading this section : Use modularized antd, thought the babel-plugin-import has ability to dynamically import styles just for the component used on the page. But now, it's cleared, the babel plugin loads all styles but saves us from manually importing the styles. Good enough :)

Comment: More importantly, it imports only the necessary JS modules, instead of all of the antd JS, which is rather huge.

Comment: oh~! so it's modularizedly loading the JS rather than the css! got ya~! thanks!